# passwd: Module is unknown

Tags: security

I have installed and running command "CIS compliance with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Applying the CIS rules to the current system" then passwd,adduser, deluser dosen't work.

```
passwd: Module is unknown
passwd: password unchanged
```

Comment: Can you give more information - a link perhaps - to what you installed?

Comment: After failure run $ sudo tail -n 2 /var/log/auth.log shows missing file /lib/security/pam_pwquality.so. I found the native libpam-pwquality does not contain this file also the "security" directory with pam_*.so files is in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security. I fixed by re-installing libpam-pwquality $sudo install libpam-pwquality then creating a link from /lib/security to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security $sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux/security /lib/security.  Note: If I do not enter a password greater than the minlen I have set in /etc/security/pwquality.conf the error message says less than 1 digits

Answer (score 3):

re-installing libpam-pwquality works. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the method above didn't work for you, maybe some settings in /etc/pam.d/common-password is preventing passwd change (for security policy reason, maybe). Comment this line and you'll be able to change password

```
# password requisite pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3 minlen=8 ucredit=-1 lcredit=-2 dcredit=-1 ocredit=-1
```